# Logical indexing failure in R

Tags: r, indexing, dataframe

I've tried reproducing this problem with the built-in data sets, but it only occurs in my own.

If we take a random subset of my data:

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(27L, 1L, 27L, 7L, 5L, 10L, 23L, 
19L, 21L, 26L), .Label = c("AC ", "AJ ", "AT ", "AWY", "BP ", 
"BW ", "CA ", "CK ", "CS ", "DJ ", "EN ", "ES ", "HF ", "HG ", 
"HL ", "HR ", "IP ", "JA ", "JG ", "JN ", "KB ", "KP ", "MJ ", 
"PC ", "RFH", "RPA", "SB ", "SG ", "TM "), class = "factor"), 
TNO = c(30L, 60L, 30L, 10000L, 10000L, 10000L, 120L, 60L, 
120L, 10000L), TNOGroup = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Good", "Poor"), class = "factor"), 
x = c(6.15, 7.75, 5.6, 3.05, 3, 4.1, 6, 3.9, 5.85, 3.75), 
View = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("Binocular", "Monocular"), class = "factor"), 
Prior = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L
), .Label = c("N", "Y"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("ID", 
"TNO", "TNOGroup", "x", "View", "Prior"), row.names = c(169L, 
49L, 24L, 16L, 9L, 4L, 35L, 18L, 164L, 36L), class = "data.frame")
```

Then try remove all instances of an ID which is a two-character string such as "SB":

```
data2 <- data[!data$ID %in% c("SB"),] # List syntax in case multiple cases
```

However, when I check the dataframe, cases with the ID "SB" still remain. When I try this with a three-character string such as "RPA", all cases with this ID are removed as is expected.

Any insights into why this might occur?

Comment: Try printing your `data.frame` with the argument `quote = TRUE` to see if any of the "CA" values have spaces around them. (`print(data, quote = TRUE)`. If they do, then you might be better off using `grep` instead of `%in%`.

Comment: Please post your data using `dput`, that way we'll have the correct structure (e.g., we'll have correctly have `ID` as a `factor` or a `character` column). It's also then easier to paste into R.

Comment: you have extra spaces, try this: `data[!data$ID %in% c("SB "),]`

Comment: If you have much trouble stripping white space with the import command, you can strip after importing using, e.g. `stringr::str_trim`. If you do this, it will be easiest to set `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` for the import, then covert to factor after trimming whitespace.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an alternative to `%in%`, I would suggest trying `grepl` as follows:

```
mydf[!grepl("CA", mydf$ID), ]
   ID   TNO TNOGroup    x      View Prior
1  AC    60     Good 5.75 Binocular     Y
2 RFH    60     Good 5.60 Monocular     N
3  BP 10000     Poor 3.00 Monocular     N
4  HG    60     Good 4.30 Binocular     Y
6  IP   120     Poor 5.50 Monocular     N
7  JG    60     Good 3.80 Monocular     Y
9 AWY 10000     Poor 3.70 Monocular     Y
```

My *suspicion* (which I can't verify without actually seeing a subset of your data provided using `dput`) is that the `"CA"` values might have spaces around them. To R, `"CA"` is not the same as `"CA "`, even if they might look the same in a `data.frame`.

---

Problems like this generally happen if there is whitespace in the file that is being read in. By default, R is conservative in deciding whether or not to remove that whitespace, but it has included the logical argument `strip.white` to use with `read.table` and family.

Thus, you might be able to avoid this problem by using:

```
read.csv("yourfile.csv", strip.white = TRUE)
```

---

Also note that this is not necessarily a *safer* or more highly recommended alternative to `%in%`. Using `grepl` might have unintended consequences. For instance, if you had another ID that was `"CAR"`, using the option I've shared would match that too.

---

#### Update

Even `strip.white` won't solve all of your problems. If your CSV has all strings quoted, and there are spaces hard-coded between the quotes, `strip.white` will honor those spaces as if they were intended.

Here's a basic example.

We'll create a CSV file where the first row of data has spaces hard-coded and the second row of data does not.

```
myTest <- tempfile()
cat(file = myTest, 'A, B, C', 
    '"AA", "BB ", "CC"', 
    '    AA,   BB   , CC', 
    sep = "\n")
```

Now, read the file in using `read.csv` with and without `strip.white = TRUE` and compare the output.

```
A <- read.csv(myTest)
B <- read.csv(myTest, strip.white = TRUE)
print(A, quote = TRUE)
#          A          B     C
# 1     "AA"     " BB " " CC"
# 2 "    AA" "   BB   " " CC"
print(B, quote = TRUE)
#      A     B    C
# 1 "AA" "BB " "CC"
# 2 "AA"  "BB" "CC"
unlink(myTest)
```

Note that in "B" for the row where the space was not hard-coded between quotes, the whitespace was trimmed appropriately, but it remains in the first row. To solve *that* problem, you might need to use some regex to strip the whitespace at the start and end of a string.

Comment: Ananda, your suspicions were correct. When creating the data frame, I definitely imported the two-character ID string as two characters - have you any idea why the space has been added?

Also, would it be considered better practice to use `grepl` rather than `%in%`?

Comment: I used `read.csv`, and now you mention it, I didn't set `strip.white = TRUE`. I've learned something today, thank you!

Comment: however, when I **do** set `strip/white = TRUE`, I still get the spaces in the ID values. Odd.

Comment: Apologies, strip.white. Second comment has typo that I can't edit.

Comment: A very complete yet succinct answer. Much appreciated!